# C# Async Sockets (*Async, SocketAsyncEventArgs)

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I've been working with the .NET 3.5 asynchronous socket API and found that ll of the *Async methods return a bool, which is `false` if the operation completed synchronously.

I'm a little confused as to how/why this could happen. It's not always an error condition, right? The MSDN examples immediately call the event handler manually in this case. Is that a good practice to follow?

Additionally, when I call `Socket.SendAsync` for instance, and attach a handler to `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed`, am I guaranteed that "Completed" is fired (or `SendAsync` returns `false`) **only** after **all** of my data has been sent? Or is it possible that it will call my handler somewhere in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may return synchronously if the action requested can be preformed instantly, for instance, if the TCP Buffer already contains the data required to complete the ReceiveAsync method, or a client is already waiting to be accepted ect.

The examples the handler because the AsyncMethod will not. I would be happy to use invoke the handler directly in this case (if there is only one subscribing). However there is a practice which suggests that you shouldn't, rather that the handler should not do anything except call another method (posibly with more meaningful params) which handles the logic - and that you should invoke this method rather than the actual event/handler.

The event will not be raised before the operation completes, Unless of course you do it manually when the async method returns true (is not complete).

From MSDN:

> Returns **true** if the I/O operation is pending. The SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed event on the e parameter **will** be raised upon **completion** of the operation.
>
> Returns **false** if the I/O operation completed synchronously. In this case, The SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed event on the e parameter **will not** be raised and the e object passed as a parameter may be examined immediately after the method call returns to retrieve the result of the operation.

Comment: When you say "the operation completes" (for SendAsync), does "complete" mean that the entire buffer of data (that you specify) has been sent? Inuitively, semantically, I am thinking "of course", but I just want to be absolutely positive.

Comment: Yeap, for that instance of SocketAsyncEventArgs. Perhaps the Socket.BeginXYZ / Socket.EndXYZ methods would be nicer (no need to worry about completing synchronously - although that info is passed to the callback aswell)